# IE9 Border Color Bug?

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-9

Can someone else take a look at this code and either confirm that this is an IE9 bug or tell me what I am doing wrong? With the following HTML code. The bottom border of the button will render the same color as the text even though a border color of red is defined. IE8 and every other browser on the planet renders this OK. Make sure that IE9 is rendering in standards mode.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
  button.button {
    color: blue;
    border: 0px;
    border-bottom: #FF0000 2px solid;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <button type="button" class="button">Update</button>
</body>
</html>
```

So far the only fix I've found for this is to redeclare a border color for all sides at the bottom of the style.

```
border-color: #FF0000;
```

Comment: very old, but I can confirm that I see this behaviour too, redeclaring the border color seems to fix it, as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

dont know it if helps checked it out its fine for me

use this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
button {
    border:0;
}

.update {
    color: blue;
    border-bottom: 2px #FF0000 solid;
    display: block;
    outline:none;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
   <button type="button" class="update">Update</button>
</body>
</html>
```

and if you accept my opinion, dont use tag names as class name

Comment: Just to clarify: this is a bug in IE9. The order of border-color, border-width and border-style inside border-bottom should not matter.

Comment: @Pumbaa80 agreed. Also, this updated example still didn't fix the problem for me. I still see the border as blue;